# ArrayList conversion to Instances object

Tags: java, casting, weka

I ve got an ArrayList testset. This list contains my data for SMO evaluation in WEKA. I want to use Evaluation weka class in order to classify my testset. In simpliest case, I had a features extracted by only one image in a ArrayList. What conversion it must be done in order to use my list in the following:

```
Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(testset); // how can I cast testset2 Instances object?
eval.evaluateModelOnce(c, data);
```

This code found from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451651/smo-sequential-minimal-optimization-in-weka): I am using it in order to train a SMO model. Train dataset contains feature extracted train  images, stored in an .arff file. In test process I am reading in my code an image I calculate the features, stored them in arrayList without stored them in .arff files. I want to cast the list directly to Instances object and proceed with classification.

EDIT: I ve tried to do something else, first connvert arrayList to array double data and to proceed as  I proceed for my trainSet:

```
int numAtts = data[0].length;
FastVector atts = new FastVector(numAtts);
for (int att = 0; att < numAtts; att++) {
 atts.addElement(new Attribute("Attribute" + att, att));
}

int numInstances = data.length;
Instances dataset = new Instances("Dataset", atts, numInstances);
for (int inst = 0; inst < numInstances; inst++) {
dataset.add(new Instance(1.0, data[inst]));
}
```

However I am received :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.management.Attribute cannot be cast to weka.core.Attribute
```

EDIT:

I change a little my code

```
double data[][] = new double[1][];
data[0] = dt;

System.out.println(args[1]);
System.out.println(args[2]);
ClothesAnalysis asdf = new ClothesAnalysis();
weka.classifiers.Classifier c = asdf.loadModel(new File(args[1]), args[2]);


String opt = ("-C 100 -K weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.NormalizedPolyKernel");
    String[] options = opt.split(" ");

int numAtts = data[0].length;
FastVector atts = new FastVector(numAtts);
for (int att = 0; att < numAtts; att++) {
 atts.addElement(new weka.core.Attribute("Attribute" + att, att));
}

int numInstances = data.length;
Instances dataset = new Instances("Dataset", atts, numInstances);
for (int inst = 0; inst < numInstances; inst++) {
 dataset.add(new Instance(1.0, data[inst]));
}

dataset.setClassIndex(dataset.numAttributes() - 1);

Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(dataset);

eval.evaluateModel(c, dataset);
System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false));
```

I am getting error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 84
at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.ReplaceMissingValues.convertInstance(ReplaceMissingValues.java:274)
at   weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.ReplaceMissingValues.input(ReplaceMissingValues.java:140
     )
at weka.classifiers.functions.SMO.distributionForInstance(SMO.java:1368)
at weka.classifiers.Classifier.classifyInstance(Classifier.java:84)
at  
  weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(Evaluation.java:1448)
at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1407)
at LBP.LBPDemo.main(LBPDemo.java:466)
```

EDIT2: My problem is that I ve got to add in the last attribute the classes labels, so I am trying to add :

```
atts.addElement(new weka.core.Attribute(" class {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}" , numAtts-1));
```

which are the indexes fo my problem. However, this isn't the proper way to add indexes to dataset. When I println the dataset in the last Attribute I get:

```
@attribute ' class {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}' numeric
```

I want to erase apostrophes and numeric in order to be read properly.

Comment: It would really help if you could specify the signatures of the testset and crossValidateModel (and probably classifier).

Comment: Cross validatedModel is not necessary in my case, since I am using just one sample. My classifier c belogns to weka class Classifier.

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.management.Attribute cannot be cast to weka.core.Attribute" - wrong import.

Comment: little code change: not sure what is the problem; EDIT2: I think that Attribute constructor do not parse its content, so I would not expect it to be working as you intended, that is just the name of the column, not the column's content.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need an [Instances](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html) object, you cannot cast an ArrayList to that.

I think you will need to use [DataSource](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/ConverterUtils.DataSource.html)'s [getDataSet()](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/ConverterUtils.DataSource.html#getDataSet%28%29) with a custom [Loader](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/Loader.html) ([constructor](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/ConverterUtils.DataSource.html#ConverterUtils.DataSource%28weka.core.converters.Loader%29)).

I guess it should work something like this:

```
new DataSource(new ListLoader(testData)).getDataSet();
```

Comment: I am trying something like: Instances data = new weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource(testset.getDataSet());
But is not what I want.

Comment: There isn't exist any method to convert ArrayList to FastVector??

Comment: I have updated my post. Do you usually read documentation? These questions seems to be answered on those pages. Also, an IDE help a lot during code exploration.

Comment: I am getting couldnt find the ListLoader class.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this answers your question thoroughly, but if you want to use 
`ArrayList<Attribute>` instead of `FastVector` as a parameter when generating instances, try implementing a new constructor for Instances:

```
 /**
   * Creates an empty set of instances. Uses the given
   * attribute information. Sets the capacity of the set of 
   * instances to 0 if its negative. Given attribute information
   * must not be changed after this constructor has been used.
   *
   * @param name the name of the relation
   * @param attInfo the attribute information
   * @param capacity the capacity of the set
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if attribute names are not unique
   */

public Instances(String name, ArrayList<Attribute> attInfo, int capacity) {

// check whether the attribute names are unique
HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
StringBuffer nonUniqueNames = new StringBuffer();
for (Attribute att: attInfo) {
  if (names.contains(att.name())) {
    nonUniqueNames.append("'" + att.name() +"' ");
  }
  names.add(att.name());
}
if (names.size() != attInfo.size())
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attribute names are not unique!" +
        " Causes: " + nonUniqueNames.toString());
names.clear();

m_RelationName = name;
m_ClassIndex = -1;
m_Attributes = attInfo;
for (int i = 0; i < numAttributes(); i++) {
  attribute(i).setIndex(i);
}
m_Instances = new ArrayList<Instance>(capacity);
}
```

... you can just copy-paste this code to weka.core.Instances class

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution for loading data from memory into weka instances. Not the most beautiful one, but it works.
Basically you generate the arff file content as a string and then create the Instances object from a `StringReader` from that string.

```
String arffString = "@relation RelationName\n\n@attribute attributeName1\n@attribute attributeName2 {No,Yes}\n\n@data\n'atribute1value',?\n";
unlabeledData = new Instances(
new BufferedReader(new StringReader(arffString)));
```